# I want to send the data to localserver

Tags: javascript, html, server, localhost

I have a html file. I can open it in mozilla firefox and it is running fine. How can I access it over local server/ localhost?

Comment: You have to run some local server that serves files, like pythons simpleHTTPserver, or php -s, or [W/L/M]AMP, etc.

Comment: put your html file on a local server. what's hard with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a local server, similar to nginx, tomcat, configure and launch it so you can access your HTML files in your browser.